# Problem with summary text in widget. Make Second row at same vertical position

Tags: css, text

[Look at image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVUdK.png)

[HTML image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4UNA.png)

This problem is difficult to explain with text, so hope the picture helps.
the code looks like this:

```
.rpwe-summary

{ display: block;
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 19px;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-left: 0px; }
```

Comment: give width to your `.rpwe-summary`.

Comment: Maybe you can show some html, so that we can see how you're implementing the css class. From your image and explanation I get the impression that you are trying to align two separate objects to the left. Not sure.

Comment: Have added an image of the HTML. It's basically #text in a div